# DialogFragment takes whole screen width

Tags: android, dialog, width

in my android app I'm using DialogFragment extending class to show custom dialogs, but I have a problem all created dialogs take whole screen width (example in photo), I would prefer it come with margin, how to do it?

[my dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH1tr.png)

Comment: Share your code that you tried so we can see what u missed

Comment: sorry, but after trying to implement any solution I found i was deleting it, leaving my dialog's class empty (just class dialog: FragmentDialog(){}) and so I don't think there's anything to show here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use style for it. You could create your custom style, like

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and `onCreate` of your `DialogFragment` subclass you can provide it as parameter

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AlertDialogStyle)
```

you can find a description of the key items in the style [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr)

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a simple and elegant solution <3